# Why my service for locations bugs when GPS is off?

Tags: android, gps, android-service, android-location

I am building an app where I am using service for locations. I am starting that service in onCreate on MainActivity, but if GPS is off my service will not look for latitude and longitude. Even if I turn on GPS after that, my service will not looking lat and long. Only when I turn on GPS before starting service(and MainActivity)  then service will work fine and it will look for locations. What Should I change to set that my service don't bug when I turn on GPS after some time that I spent in app?
This is my location service:

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
protected static final String TAG = "LocationUpdateService";
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
public static Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
protected String mLastUpdateTime;
protected String timeWhenStartLocationUpdates;
protected String timeWhenStopLocationUpdates;
protected String timeWhenServiceDestroyed;
protected String connectionFailed;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected Location mCurrentLocation;
protected String timeWhenGetInGetLatLong;
protected String report_time;
protected String timeFromElse;
public static boolean isEnded = false;
Calendar calendar;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended==");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    Log.d("mCurrentLocation", "Location is: " + location);
    getLatLong();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("TimeWhenCameToOnLocationChanged", mLastUpdateTime);
    editor.apply();
    Log.d("onLocationchanged", "OnLocationChangedInServiceLocation");
    Log.d("Time ", "Time of lat and long from Service: " + mLastUpdateTime);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    connectionFailed = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("connectionFailed", connectionFailed);
    editor.apply();
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("LOC", "Service init...");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient===");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

public void getLatLong() {
    timeWhenGetInGetLatLong = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    if (mCurrentLocation != null && mLastUpdateTime != null) {

        String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        report_time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        Log.d("preferences", "Time stored in preferences: " + mLastUpdateTime);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("user_latitude", lat);
        editor.putString("user_longitude", lng);
        editor.putString("getLatLongIf", "ok");
        editor.putString("report_time_for_location_response", report_time);
        editor.putString("time_when_comes_to_getLatLong", timeWhenGetInGetLatLong);
        editor.apply();
    }else{
        timeFromElse = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("getLatLongElse", timeFromElse);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    timeWhenStartLocationUpdates = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("startLocationUpdates", timeWhenStartLocationUpdates);
        editor.apply();
        Log.i("startUpdates", " startLocationUpdates===" + timeWhenStartLocationUpdates);
        isEnded = true;
    }
}
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        timeWhenStopLocationUpdates = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("stopLocationUpdates", timeWhenStopLocationUpdates);
        editor.apply();
        Log.d("stopUpdates", "stopLocationUpdates();==" + timeWhenStopLocationUpdates);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timeWhenServiceDestroyed = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("onDestroyService", timeWhenServiceDestroyed);
    editor.apply();
    stopLocationUpdates();
    Log.d("onDestroyService", "onDestroy: + " + timeWhenServiceDestroyed);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    isEnded = false;
    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    mLastUpdateTime = "";
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    Log.d("onCreateService", "onCreateService");
}
```

Again, I am starting my service in onCreate on Main activity...
Could anyone helps me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your service is call only first time. Please check your service. It is running multiple time or not.

Comment: can you try my way how i'm doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds

Comment: Yes, my service is running multiple times.

Comment: @Saveen Thanks for answer, but I would not like to completely changing my code..would you be kind just to tell me what should I add into this mine code?

Comment: @Bansal So, You think that I put logic from onCreate to onStartCommand or not?

Comment: Your service is not working permanently

Answer (score 0):

Please check how i have changed service to your code.

**Step 1. Make this class 
GoogleLocationService.java**

```
public class GoogleLocationService {
private GoogleServicesCallbacks callbacks = new GoogleServicesCallbacks();
LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener;
Context activity;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;


public GoogleLocationService(Context activity, LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener) {
    this.locationUpdateListener = locationUpdateListener;
    this.activity = activity;
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(callbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(callbacks)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

private class GoogleServicesCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               String connectionFailed = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("connectionFailed", connectionFailed);
editor.apply();
Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        }
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
                locationUpdateListener.updateLocation(location);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean locationEnabled(Context context) {
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gps_enabled;
}

private boolean servicesConnected(Context context) {
    return isPackageInstalled(GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_PACKAGE, context);
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


public void startUpdates() {
    /*
     * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here; instead, wait
     * for onResume()
     */
    if (servicesConnected(activity)) {
        if (locationEnabled(activity)) {
            locationUpdateListener.canReceiveLocationUpdates();
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to get your location.Please turn on your device Gps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        locationUpdateListener.cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Google play service not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//stop location updates
public void stopUpdates() {
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

//start location updates
private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, callbacks);
        String timeWhenStartLocationUpdates = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("startLocationUpdates", timeWhenStartLocationUpdates);
    editor.apply();
    }
}

public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, callbacks);
         String timeWhenStopLocationUpdates = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("stopLocationUpdates", timeWhenStopLocationUpdates);
    editor.apply();
    }
}

public void startGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void closeGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

 }
```

**Step2. Make this interface 
LocationUpdateListener.java**

```
 public interface LocationUpdateListener {

/**
 * Called immediately the service starts if the service can obtain location
 */
void canReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called immediately the service tries to start if it cannot obtain location - eg the user has disabled wireless and
 */
void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates();

/**
 * Called whenever the location has changed (at least non-trivially)
 * @param location
 */
void updateLocation(Location location);

/**
 * Called when GoogleLocationServices detects that the device has moved to a new location.
 * @param localityName The name of the locality (somewhere below street but above area).
 */
void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location);
}
```

**Step 3. Make this Location service class
LocationUpdateService.java**

```
 public class LocationUpdateService extends Service {

 protected String mLastUpdateTime;
 protected String timeWhenServiceDestroyed;
 protected String timeWhenGetInGetLatLong;
 protected String report_time;
 protected String timeFromElse;
 Calendar calendar;

 private GoogleLocationService googleLocationService;
 IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
 public LocationUpdateService getServerInstance() {
    return LocationUpdateService.this;
}
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return mBinder;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d("LOC", "Service init...");
return Service.START_STICKY;
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient===");
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
createLocationRequest();
  }

  public void getLatLong() {
timeWhenGetInGetLatLong = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

  if (mCurrentLocation != null && mLastUpdateTime != null) {

    String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    report_time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.d("preferences", "Time stored in preferences: " + mLastUpdateTime);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("user_latitude", lat);
    editor.putString("user_longitude", lng);
    editor.putString("getLatLongIf", "ok");
    editor.putString("report_time_for_location_response", report_time);
    editor.putString("time_when_comes_to_getLatLong", timeWhenGetInGetLatLong);
    editor.apply();
}else{
    timeFromElse = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("getLatLongElse", timeFromElse);
    editor.apply();
 }
 }


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
timeWhenServiceDestroyed = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("onDestroyService", timeWhenServiceDestroyed);
editor.apply();
  if (googleLocationService != null) {
    googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
  }
  Log.d("onDestroyService", "onDestroy: + " + timeWhenServiceDestroyed);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();

 mLastUpdateTime = "";

Log.d("onCreateService", "onCreateService");

 googleLocationService = new GoogleLocationService(context, new LocationUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void canReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    @Override
    public void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates() {
    }

    //update location to our servers for tracking purpose
    @Override
    public void updateLocation(Location location) {
        if (location != null ) {
           mCurrentLocation = location;
mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
Log.d("mCurrentLocation", "Location is: " + location);
getLatLong();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_location", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("TimeWhenCameToOnLocationChanged", mLastUpdateTime);
editor.apply();
Log.d("onLocationchanged", "OnLocationChangedInServiceLocation");
Log.d("Time ", "Time of lat and long from Service: " + mLastUpdateTime);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location) {

        googleLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
    }
});
googleLocationService.startUpdates();

}
```

Try this, hope this help you. Remember you will get updated latitude and longitude on **updateLocation**.

Comment: Thanks mate, but where you saw that my service isn't working permanently?

Comment: Later I saw their is start sticky present in your service

Comment: Try it my way if still you get any problem then let me know

Comment: Okay, so just tu try this part of code that you write me for now, not that whole your function from another question?

Comment: I tried this but its the same problem..when I go into app and then I turn on location it doesn't appera icon of location in notification bar..but when I again go into app that icon is hsowed in the bar....so that means that my location don't work when I go first time into app.

Comment: I have  updated my answe and please check why you are not getting  location on location changed or update ? First time your method get location is not working because location start updating after call of this method.