# Fused Location Provider not updating fast enough

Tags: android, performance, fusedlocationproviderapi

A while ago I wrote a Unity program which logged GPS coordinates and it got a new location about 3 times a second while driving. I'm rewritting the app in Android Studio and using the fused location provider API. It is very slow and only getting GPS coordinates ever 5-15 seconds while driving. Here are some snips of my code which I believe influence the speed of getting a location.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    ...
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15*1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    ...
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mylongitude = location.getLongitude();
    ....
```

In order for this app to be viable it needs to log GPS coordinates at least a few times per second. Should I go back to the android.location method for location even though it is advised against?

**How do I speed up receiving GPS coordinates?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing here here interval 10 seconds and fastest interval 15 seconds.You just pass minimum seconds.

And fastest means pass the at least half of your Normal time Interval.
Try this way and let me know if you get any problem.

Just remove it and pass here like this.

```
public final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 2000;
public final long UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS );
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS );
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097) please check for more info.

Thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: Looks like it's working!!! Thanks so much. searched a lot and did not find the answer you previously posted. hopefully this will be easier to find for folks in the future. Your Rock. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: I am using fused location i am having a issue when my app is in foreground i am getting update frequently but  when my app is in background i am getting less frequent updates please help me!!

Comment: Due to updated OS maybe you get a problem with Service. Can you try with another way like JobScheduler? Fused API also get updated Please check that too.