# Google Map: Updating Location while moving?

Tags: android

This function is suppose to pinpoint your current location so I tried using nox and changed my location so it does update while moving however my icon is not following

The only thing that pinpoints my new location is the blue point.

can someone explain why the icon is not changing.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),          location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.i149));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097

Comment: Use this code inside locationchanged in fused api