# How to get Google Location API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, google-maps-android-api-1

I request the current location when I initialize the app, but it is not working. The map starts and it has nothing requested. Can anyone please solve this?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.leonardo.myapplicationmap;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiCliente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (googleServicesAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Play Services compativel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initMap();


        } else {
           /* Toast.makeText(this, "Play Services incompativel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(layout.activity_main);*/
        }
    }

    private void initMap() {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }


    public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possível conectar ao Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;

    }

    private void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title("I am here!"));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);

    }

    public void geoLocate(View view) throws IOException {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        String location = et.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);

        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address address = list.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = address.getLatitude();
        double lng = address.getLongitude();
        goToLocationZoom(lat, lng, 15);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        //goToLocationZoom(-23.6479053,-46.5756496,17);


  /*      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);*/
        mGoogleApiCliente = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiCliente.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mapTypeNone:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeSatellitee:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiCliente, mLocationRequest, this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sem coneção", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sem posição atual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            LatLng ll =new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,17);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Did you enable Location updates in your phone's settings? Did you grant location persmissions to your app?

Comment: can you look into this, after getting location set camera move to current location http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds