# Wait for 5 seconds

Tags: android, wait

I want to wait 5 seconds before starting another public void method. The thread sleep was not working for me. If there is a way of `wait()` without using Threads I would love to know that.

```
public void check(){
    //activity of changing background color of relative layout
}
```

I want to wait 3 seconds before changing the relative layout color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause / sleep thread or process in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Comment: @till as specified i checked these but they did not work for me,yet thanks for considering :)

Comment: Cannot actually see the difference between the answer of the referenced question and your selected answer...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

just add one-liner with lambda

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(this::yourMethod, 5000);
```

edit for clarification: `yourMethod` refers to the method which you want to execute after 5000 milliseconds.

Comment: Good and fast solution, but this one will not work for all of needs. Good example - when you need to wait before executing / calling activity method from Adapter.

Comment: is this synchronous or asynchronous ?

Comment: this does not really wait does it, it just executes a function at a later time . . .

Comment: (new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(null, 5000); as no augument constructure is depricated and if you want to wait without any method call pass null

Answer (score 97):

See if this works for you.  Be sure to import the `android.os.Handler`

```
      Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // yourMethod();
                }
            }, 5000);   //5 seconds
```

or Kotlin

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    // yourMethod()
}, 5000)
```

Comment: It gives an error saying Handler is an Abstract cannot be instantiated

Comment: I think it's an error from my side,i'll check it again with a fresh mind tomorrow

Comment: Use this Handler `android.os.Handler`. You're using the logging Handler and that one doesn't have a `postDelay` method. You're also getting that not initiated error cause you have to implement some methods to it cause you're using the Logging handler

Comment: This one should be an answer.

Answer (score 13):

you can use java handlers to achieve your task:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     // Actions to do after 5 seconds
    }
}, 5000);
```

for more information read the following url:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 6):

For import use: `import android.os.Handler;`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // yourMethod();
    }
}, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

> **This works for me:**
>
> ```
>     val handler = Handler()
>     handler.postDelayed({
>         // your code to run after 2 second
>     }, 2000)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

what I prefer is

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(this::here is your method,2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the parameterless constructor of the Handler class is now deprecated on Android 11 and above, if you use the above code it will throw a deprecation warning:
'Handler()' is deprecated as of API 30: Android 11.0 (R).
You should now specify the Looper in the constructor via the Looper.getMainLooper() method as following:
Java

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your Code
    }
}, 5000);
```

Kotlin

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    // Your Code
}, 5000)
```

[java - What do I use now that Handler() is deprecated? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851895/16216985)

Answer (score 0):

One line in Java 8

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> check(), 3000);
```

This is clean and nice for reading

Answer (score -1):

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067512/how-to-make-android-wait/51456313#51456313) to another question, but it may also help you.

Class:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

public class Waiter {

WaitListener waitListener;
int waitTime = 0;
Handler handler;
int waitStep = 1000;
int maxWaitTime = 5000;
boolean condition = false;

public Waiter(Looper looper, final int waitStep, final int maxWaitTime){

    handler = new Handler(looper);
    this.waitStep = waitStep;
    this.maxWaitTime = maxWaitTime;

}

public void start(){

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            waitListener.checkCondition();

            if (condition) {

                waitListener.onConditionSuccess();

            } else {
                if (waitTime <= maxWaitTime) {

                    waitTime += waitStep;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, waitStep);

                } else {

                    waitListener.onWaitEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void setConditionState(boolean condition){
    this.condition = condition;
}

public void setWaitListener(WaitListener waitListener){
    this.waitListener = waitListener;
}

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface WaitListener {

public void checkCondition();

public void onWaitEnd();

public void onConditionSuccess();

}
```

Usage example:

```
ConnectivityManager mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final int result = mConnMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableMMS");

final Waiter waiter = new Waiter(getMainLooper(), 1000, 5000);
waiter.setWaitListener(new WaitListener() {

            @Override
            public void checkCondition() {
                Log.i("Connection", "Checking connection...");
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = mConnMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS);
                waiter.setConditionState(networkInfo.isConnected());
            }

            @Override
            public void onWaitEnd() {
                Log.i("Connection", "No connection for sending");
                //DO
            }

            @Override
            public void onConditionSuccess() {
                Log.i("Connection", "Connection success, sending...");
                //DO
            }

});

waiter.start();
```

Comment: You should really include the relevant parts of the linked answer in your own, unless it is better suited as a comment.