# Follow user's location in Real - time google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I want to Follow user's location every time it moves but the camera is not focusing on the user's location when the user moves.

Here's my onlocationchanged

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
         latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);



        //Place current location marker

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.kikomarke1r11)));
        Toast.makeText(traffic.this, "Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f", latitude, longitude));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
    }
```

I tried to remove:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
```

But then when i removed it, i succesfully focused the camera to the user's location when the user moves, the downside of it ,  The camera is constantly updating towards user's location even thought the user is not moving

Comment: why you are not tried with google fused api ?

Comment: Enlighten me please.

Comment: Please take a look from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097