# locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null

Tags: android, gps, android-location, android-gps

I am making a program and i want to get gps coordinates  of my device.The problem is that when locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() is called it returns null.My device runs android 4.4 API 19.

Here is my code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {    

private TextView latituteField;

private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 0, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("location change:", " change1  " );
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

and this is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vaggelis.location">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: maybe it just doesn't know your location at the moment you ask for it?

Comment: this is my code..what do you mean if i ask for it?

Comment: ok, you use only GSP provider. Are you sure that GPS is turned on?

Comment: yes it is.do i have to turn on something else except GPS?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below the link and use the code, it's working and tested.

https://medium.com/@ssaurel/getting-gps-location-on-android-with-fused-location-provider-api-1001eb549089

Answer (score -1):

**locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null.**

Beacuse everytime it takes time to get last location from your phone.It very old and not good approach.

Google introduces **fused api** for android. It always return correct value.

I have already answer same [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097). Just look at this.If you get any problem then let me know.

Thanks

Comment: it says for  GoogleApiClient and LocationRequest cannot resolve symbol.Do you know why is that?(My device is running android 4.4 API 19)

Comment: did you add **com.google.android.gms:play-services-location** in your gradle ?

Comment: now it is okay thank you.I have two problems: 1) in my manifest file ".service.location.LocationService" says: unresolved calss 'LocatioService , Validates resource references inside Android XML files 2)In my main activity in onCreate method i call  startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class)); like you said .but with what does context needs to be initialized? 
sorry for the trouble

Comment: I have used **LocationService** class because i need location in background as well. You can do without this also by using **GoogleLocationService** method. Please read my other answer i have mention everything.