# onLocationChanged getting called once (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to detect changes in current location in my code using onLocationChanged() method but its not getting called when my location is changing.

Also I noticed from log that onConnected() is also not getting called means callbacks are not happening totally after initialization.

Attaching the code
`

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 

    OnMapReadyCallback,

    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,

    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,

    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Initializing
    MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations
            if (MarkerPoints.size() > 1) {
                MarkerPoints.clear();
                mMap.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            MarkerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
             * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
             * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
             */
            if (MarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            } else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }


            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            mMap.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                FetchUrl.execute(url);
                //move map camera
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
            }

        }
    });

}

private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}

/**
 * A method to download json data from url
 */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
            Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points ;

        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);



            Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
        }

    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    Log.d("BuildApIClient","Connection");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("onConnected","EntryPoint");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("onConnected","LocationUpdates");
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    //On Path logic

    double tolerance = 10;
    boolean isLocationOnPath = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng,MarkerPoints,true,tolerance);

    if(!isLocationOnPath){
        Log.d("onLocationonPath","NO");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Not on route",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Log.d("onLocationonPath","Yes");
    }
    Log.d("inside onlocationchange","Yes");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}}`
```

Comment: already answer here try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097

Answer (score 1):

there no need to Create new `LocationRequest` object in `onConnected()` every time.

try using this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}


protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    startLocationUpdates();
}


 protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    //YOUR CODES
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
    }
}
```

1. Create `LocationRequest` and `GoogleApiClient` in `onCreate()`
2. Connect the apiClient in `onStart()` and disconnect in `onStop()`
3. Start your Location Update in `onResume()` and `onConnected()`

Answer (score 0):

Its done , problem was here

//stop location updates

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```