# GPS is fluctuating when the device moves slowly or stands still

Tags: java, android, gps, accelerometer

I am facing an issue with the data provided from `GPS.`

I am calculating the `distance upon the location change callback`, so when the device is idle the distance getting incremented due to the GPS fluctuation.

I have been using **FusedLocationProviderClient** for getting the location update.

```
 fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                   locationCallback, Looper.myLooper()); 




fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                    onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                }
            };


 private void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

Comment: try to use high accuracy   `mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)`

Comment: take a reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds/39315097#39315097

Comment: @Saveen already it's "LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_A‌​ACCURACY" i have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positioning accuracy of GPS is not better than 4 or 5 meters. that is, each time a position is calculated it can be within a radius never less than about 4 meters. Some time the calculated position will be displaced meters to the front, sometimes to the left, back, etc.

If you want those small variations not to be taken into account, it must be your code that discriminates if the user has really moved.

It sounds difficult, yes, but this is the merit for an application or GPS device to calculate near to correct distances.

Comment: How do we know if the user has really moved?

Comment: Can we do it checking the distance change or by the some sensors??

Comment: How do we know if the user has really moved?: that's the question of the million dollars ! hehe, I only know that devices such as Garmin use very complicated algorithms. Sensors ? The accelerations of a person walking are so weak that I think almost impossible to be useful, also the accuracy of the sensors of a mobile phone is low.

Answer (score 1):

Lluis Felisart is correct. There are random-seeming fluctuations in the Locations reported in the callback.

One simple thing you can try is, in your `LocationCallback` check `LocationResult.getLocations()` where the last two elements will be the two most recent `Location`s you've received. For these two `Location`s, compare the sum of their `getAccuracy()` values, times some fudge factor `K`, with the distance between these same two `Location`s. If the resulting accuracy is less than the distance between the locations, ignore the location update. This is definitely not perfect but will filter out some noise.

Perhaps a more advanced approach that may work better is to compute a weighted moving average of `Location`s in `LocationResult.getLocations()`. You can weight each `Location` by its `getAccuracy()` value.